# Can you display more than one column aggregate values in groupHeader

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid

I have a grid where I'm showing users for different regions. Here are the columns

```
| Name | Region | Registered |
```

Is it possible to group by Region and in the group header display a count of registered users
e.g

```
| Name | Region | Registered |
Region : London (Registered: 2)
| Martin | London | 1 |
| John| London | 1 |
| Ted | London | 0 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the column you want to group by and set the custom text, set the groupHeaderTemplate to a function, and you can return whatever you want to display for the group by text.

```
columns: [ { field: 'name', groupHeaderTemplate: groupHeaderName },
```

With the function groupHeaderName...

```
function groupHeaderName(e) {
    // Do whatever you need to here.
    var items = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    return e.value + " from total: " + items.length;   // or whatever you need to do.
}
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/IbITaT/5/edit